# About setState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Below is a function getting messages from firebase database, but it only `setState` to only one message.

However, the `console.log` can log multiple messages in the object.
Is there anything wrong in my function?

```
getMessages(){
var messages = [];
firebaseApp.database().ref('users/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/userChat/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).orderByValue().limitToLast(10).once('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
  //alert(JSON.stringify(dataSnapshot.val()));
  dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
    firebaseApp.database().ref('messages').child(child.key).once("value", (message)=>{
      //alert(JSON.stringify(messages));
      messages.push({
        _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
        text: message.val().text,
        createdAt: new Date(message.val().timestamp),
        user: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 'Developer',
        },
      });
      this.setState({
        messages: messages
      });
      console.log('woooo'+JSON.stringify(messages));
    });
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You are setting the state inside the `forEach` Block. try moving it outside the iteration block</s>

As JanneKlouman mentioned it's not good enough to remove it from the iterration block as you are doing async calls. 
You can create a new array and set it in the state on each iteration, react will batch those set state calls:

```
function getMessages() {
  var messages = [];
  firebaseApp.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userChat/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).orderByValue().limitToLast(10).once('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(dataSnapshot.val()));
    dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
      firebaseApp.database().ref('messages').child(child.key).once("value", (message) => {
        const newMessage = {
          _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
          text: message.val().text,
          createdAt: new Date(message.val().timestamp),
          user: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'Developer',
          },
        }
        const nextState = this.state.messages.map(message => {
          return {
            ...message,
            user: {...meesage.user} // i think we must do this in order to break out of the reference as spreading will only work on a shallow level
          }
        });
        this.setState({
          messages: [...nextState, newMessage]
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be equivalent to `this.setState({ messages: [] })`, as it's run before the messages firebase callbacks are fired?

Comment: @JanneKlouman looks like you are right, its out of the 2nd `ref` scope.

Comment: is there a way to save all the messages in a variable first and then setState once only?

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the array before setting state:

```js
getMessages(){
  let messages = [];
  firebaseApp.database().ref('users/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/userChat/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).orderByValue().limitToLast(10).once('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
    dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
      firebaseApp.database().ref('messages').child(child.key).once("value", (message)=>{
        const message = {
          _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
          text: message.val().text,
          createdAt: new Date(message.val().timestamp),
          user: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'Developer',
          },
        };

        // Clone messages
        messages = [...messages, message];

        this.setState({ messages });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: the `spread` operator only works on one level deep, that means `meesage.user` will keep that reference to the object in the state.